# Can we call a JS function written for one event on other event?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I need to call a function on 2 events.

```
On first event, f1() is called.
On second event, f1(), f2() are called.
```

Can I call f1() on second event without mentioning f1() (Using first event)?

Comment: If you are able to to trigger the first event when the second event occurs, then yes, but that might not be what you want (depends on what the implications of triggering the first event are). I think you have to be a bit more concrete about your use case.

Comment: yo can dispatch first event when second event is called.

Comment: if `f1()` is declared outside the event handler you can call it as often as you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! If `f1()` is called when "first event" is triggered, just make sure you trigger "first event" whenever you're responding to "second event."

I imagine some variations might look like:

```
var firstEvent = function() {
  f1();
}

var secondEvent = function() {
  f2();
  firstEvent();
}
```

OR

```
this.on('firstEvent', function() {
  f1();
});

this.on('secondEvent', (function() {
  f2();
  this.trigger('firstEvent');
}).bind(this));
```